# How can I change the (x, y) pair with a generic relation between them?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I want to create a generic function to check if every 2 consecutive elements in a list are in a relation given by the user as input (eg: <, >, ==)

```
ordonata :: [a] -> (a -> a -> Bool) -> Bool
ordonata [] f    = True
ordonata list f  = and (map (\(x, y) -> f x y ) (zip list (tail(list))))
```

The program compiles, but when I try the input "ordonata[1, 2, 3, 4] < " I get this error:

"parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)"

Comment: try `ordonata [1,2,3,4] (<)` - the key part being the parentheses around the `<` operator. When passing an operator to a higher-order function you always need the parentheses.

Comment: @RobinZigmond More accurately, when trying to use an operator as a function. This could be passing it, or it could be returning it; or it could simply be using it infix for some reason, e.g. `(<) 2 3`.

Comment: Apart from `(<)`, some minor comments: `(tail(list))` can be written as `(tail list)`. `and (map predicate) list` can be written `all predicate list`. Tricky point: you do not need the empty case, since `zip [] (tail [])` will return the empty list without triggering the error on `tail []`. Hence, `ordonata list f = all (uncurry f) (zip list (tail list))` should work.

Comment: or `and (zipWith (uncurry f) list (tail list))`

Comment: Small fix: `zipWith` doesn't need an uncurried function, so it's just `and (zipWith f list (tail list))`, or using the `Applicative` instance for functions, `and (zipWith f <*> tail $ list)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is correct!

When passing operators like `>` as a function Haskell requires brackets around the operator: `(>)`.

You can use your function like this:

```hs
ordonata [1, 2, 3, 4] (<)
```

Looks like you're getting the hang of things!

A few notes on style; firstly, most Haskell developers would swap the argument order of the function to:

```
ordonata :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

because it's more amenable to currying; with this version we can easily define partially applied functions:

```
ascending = ordanata (<)
descending = ordanata (>)
allEq = ordanata (==)
```

Also you might want to check out `zipWith`; we can use it to clean things up a little:

```
ordonata :: [a] -> (a -> a -> Bool) -> Bool
ordonata [] f    = True
ordonata list f  = and (zipWith f list (tail list))
```